# Are there plans for an Ubuntu-approved, Docker-official Snappy baseimage?

Tags: ubuntu-core, docker

Like (I suspect) a lot of folks, I'd like to see a Canonical-created or -endorsed Snappy baseimage for Docker. Does anyone know if that is likely to be forthcoming, or if it is being worked on?

Comment: You probably need to ask the people that created docker. I would assume they need to provide it (?)